# How to change gcs bucket permission ? google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I'm trying to change the bucket permission for my google app engine project, the bucket is the default one.
but I couldn't ! why ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the UI doesn't work without billing enabled, however you can still modify bucket permissions using the 'gsutil' command.

**acl - Get, set, or change bucket and/or object ACLs**
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl